# How to prove a linear algorithm that identifies all cycles and the length in a graph where each vertex has exactly one outgoing edge

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

> Consider a directed graph on n vertices, where each vertex has exactly
>   one outgoing edge. This graph consists of a collection of cycles as
>   well as additional vertices that have paths to the cycles, which we
>   call the branches. Describe a linear time algorithm that identifies
>   all of the cycles and computes the length of each cycle. You can
>   assume that the input is given as an array A, where A[i] is the
>   neighbor of i, so that the graph has the edge (i, A[i]).

So far my approach to the algorithm is basically marking the vertices I have traversed, and every time a vertex points back to the ones that I've traversed I count one cycle and move on to the next unvisited vertex. During the process, I also have a hashmap or something to record the order in which each node is traversed so I can calculate the length whenever I identify a cycle. (Would that be linear?) However, I very new to proof and I have no idea how to justify the correctness of an algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Is the algorithm allowed to use extra O(n) memory (e.g. mark if the vertex is already visited?)

Comment: The problem is that the description of your algorithm is vague, so it's impossible to tell whether the algorithm you would implement is correct or not.   First, be specific.  And use arrays instead of hash maps, so you can have real linear time instead of expected linear time.

Comment: @kfx memory does not seem to be a problem

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it got downvoted in cstheory so...

Comment: @MattTimmermans oh yea pseudocode would be sufficient for now and I'm more stressed about the proof that's why I kinda glossed over the algorithm.

Comment: That might because you don't really have a good description of the algorithm. A formal proof that an algorithm work is rigorous work, you need both the algorithm and proof written up in a certain format, not just a "so far ..." description. This looks like homework, don't you have classmates to discuss with? Also, don't you have textbooks or other source material that go over the criteria for a formal proof and algorithm?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I see. Sorry if I'm wasting people's time. Sadly not a lot of us know what is going on because this class literally asked us to write proofs (or justify algos more like in this case) with, not kidding, zero lectures/prereqs on how to do one, and the homework guideline couldn't be vaguer.

Comment: I don't know much about formal proofs, other than that I can understand that I am looking at one, when I am. The most typical way I see proofs are done is with induction and reduction. If you can prove that the algorithm works for some basic set of inputs, like 0, 1, 2 or 3, as an example, and then that you can prove that if you can take any larger input sets and reduce them to problems consisting of 0, 1, 2 or 3 elements (again, example), and that the algorithm works with the subproblems, then that usually does it.

Comment: note that the quoted question does not ask for a *formal* proof.  If you know that your algorithm works, you only need to explain *how* you know that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for the explanation. I would try to do what you guys suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use extra memory, the algorithm in Python would be like this.

```
colors = [0] ** N; # initialize N element array withe values of zero (not seen)
for i in range(N):
    v = i # current vertex
    if colors[v] != 0: continue # already seen
    colors[v] = 1 # seen
    v = A[v] # move to neighbor
    while colors[v] == 0:
       colors[v] = 1
       v = A[v] # move to neighbor
    # we have reached previously seen node; this is the start node of a cycle
    colors[v] = 2 # mark the start of a cycle
    cycle_len = 1
    v = A[v] # move to neighbor
    while colors[v] == 1:
       cycle_len += 1
       v = A[v] # move to neighbor
   print("got a cycle with length =", cycle_len)
```

The basic idea is to use three colors to differently mark nodes that have already been visited and nodes that are the starting points of cycles; obviously, a single node can only belong to a single cycle.

The algorithm is linear as the internal `while` loop is only executed for nodes that have not been previously seen. Nodes already seen are skipped. In the worst case, both internal while loops are fully executed, but 2*N is still O(N).

Using a hashmap would not match the requirements, as the worst-case time complexity for hashmaps is not linear.

Comment: Implementation and proof are two completely different things. A formal proof of an algorithm is *very* formal.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry I made it sounds like it needs a formal proof, but it sort of only require justifying the algorithm